# What are the characters on this unusual seal (Characters identified: 令憲稽首)

Tags: character-identification, seal

Can someonne help me to decipher this unusual seal ?
Many thanks

[image]

Side carving of this seal

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters are

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

which would be expressed today as 「令憲稽首」. This roughly translates to *prostrate before the law*.

---

What you have there looks like a seal recorded to be carved by an artisan named 黄士陵. See http://www.ne.jp/asahi/yoshitaka/hanko/kousiryou.html:

[image]

The side says

> 仿彝器文 士陵
>
> *In imitation of [bronze inscriptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions), by* 士陵

referring to the script style of the seal being bronze inscription shapes.

Comment: Thanks for the side carving translation.
By the way, how did you found the japanese web site about this seal ?